# Embbeding youtube video in WKWebView not working

Tags: ios, swift, embed, wkwebview

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in a `WKWebView` in swift 4. I don't know if I'm doing it well because I'm new using the `WKWebView` (at least the code works fine with a webView). So this is the code:

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView2: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let width = self.view.frame.width
        let height = width/320 * 180


        let videoEmbedString = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe frameBorder=\"0\" height=\""
        let one = String(describing: height) + "\" width=\"" + String(describing: width) + "\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"

        let id = "ojbb6nGvIi8"

        let parameters = "?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&frameborder=0&rel=0&loop=1&playlist=\(id)\"></iframe></body></html>"


        let final = videoEmbedString + one + id + parameters

        webView2 = WKWebView()


        if let url = URL(string:final) {

            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView2.load(request)
        }

        view.addSubview(webView2)

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are two issues :

**Issue 1 :**

```
//final is HTML String not an URL

 if let url = URL(string:final) { 

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView2.load(request)
}
```

So it never gets inside the if Block

You should use

```
 webView2.loadHTMLString(final, baseURL: nil)
```

**Issue 2:**
There is no frame for webView2. You will need to set frame for webView2

```
webView2.frame = view.bounds // any frame size as per your need.
```

Adding these two will solve you problem.

Comment: The video works fine, but on the screen, it appears with a width of 30 and a height of 40 (something like that). I put these lines in the code: webView2 = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300));;;;; webView2.loadHTMLString(final, baseURL: nil). Do you know how can I fix that, so the width and the height works fine???

Comment: yes, you will have to change the iFrame height in variable one .I have made one sample change you can use it see the change.       let one = "500px\" width=\"100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"